# How to check that list elements exists in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the column in my dataframe containing list of strings of vary length as shown below :

```
           names                                            venue
 
[Instagrammable, Restaurants, Vegan]                          14 Hills
[Date Night, Vibes, Drinks]                                   Upper 14
[Date Night, Drinks, After Work Drinks, Cocktail]             Hills
            .                                                   .                  
            .                                                   .
            .
```

Now if i want to check that if some list is present in my dataframe or not , How to do it .

```
Example1:

Input :
        find_list=[Date Night, Vibes, Drinks]
        venue = 'Upper 14'
Output:
        Record is present in my dataframe

Example 2:

Input :
        find_list=[Date Night, Drinks]
        venue='Hills 123'
Output:
        Record is not present in my dataframe
```

Example

```
Input :
        find_list=[   Date Night, Vibes, Drinks]
        venue = 'Upper 14'
Output:
        Record is not present in my dataframe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.apply()` and `.any()`:

```py
find_list = ["Date Night", "Vibes", "Drinks"]

if df["names"].apply(lambda x: x == find_list).any():
    print("List is present in my dataframe")
else:
    print("List is not present in my dataframe")
```

Prints:

```
List is present in my dataframe
```

---

EDIT: To match a record:

```py
find_list = ["Date Night", "Vibes", "Drinks"]
venue = "Upper 14"

if df.apply(
    lambda x: x["names"] == find_list and x["venue"] == venue, axis=1
).any():
    print("Record is present in my dataframe")
else:
    print("Record is not present in my dataframe")
```

Prints:

```
Record is present in my dataframe
```

---

EDIT 2: To strip whitespaces from input list:

```py
find_list = ["      Date Night", "Vibes", "Drinks"]
venue = "Upper 14"

if df.apply(
    lambda x: all(a.strip() == b.strip() for a, b in zip(x["names"], find_list))
    and x["venue"] == venue,
    axis=1,
).any():
    print("Record is present in my dataframe")
else:
    print("Record is not present in my dataframe")
```

Prints:

```
Record is present in my dataframe
```

---

EDIT 3: To remove extra spaces between words:

```py
import re

find_list = ["      Date     Night", "Vibes", "Drinks"]
venue = "Upper 14"

r = re.compile(r"\s{2,}")

if df.apply(
    lambda x: all(
        r.sub(a.strip(), " ") == r.sub(b.strip(), " ")
        for a, b in zip(x["names"], find_list)
    )
    and x["venue"] == venue,
    axis=1,
).any():
    print("Record is present in my dataframe")
else:
    print("Record is not present in my dataframe")
```

Comment: What is I have to match the complete record / row as shown in above question , edited !

Comment: If I give some space in any of values in lists , because lists value are strings, it does not giving correct output as I have edited my question !

Comment: Well , It is working but not suitable answer because it remove extra white spaces after and before from the word , if I give the space between word like Date       Night , it does not handle this

Comment: @Haseeb Well, then you need to properly clean your data before doing the checks.

Comment: Can you write that code for me that can remove the spaces between words , It should remain a single only